# MySQL data file won't shrink

Tags: mysql

My ibdata1 file for MySQL database grew to about 32GB over time. Recently I deleted about 10GB of data from my databases (and restarted mysql for good measure), but the file won't shrink. Is there any way to reduce the size of this file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file size of InnoDB tablespaces will never reduce automatically, no matter how much data you delete.

What you could do, although it is a lot of effort, is to create one tablespace for every table by setting

```
innodb_file_per_table
```

The long part about this is, that you need to export ALL DATA from the mysql server (setting up a new server would be easier) and then reimport the data. Instead of one single ibdata1 file which holds the data for each and every table, you will find a lot of files called `tablename.ibd` which hold the data only for one single table.

---

Afterwards:

When you then delete a lot of data from tables, you can let mysql recreate the data-file by issuing

```
alter table <tablename> engine=myisam;
```

to switch to MyIsam (and have the InnoDB data file for this table deleted) and then

```
alter table <tablename> engine=innodb;
```

to recreate the table.

Comment: the alternate won't work if you have FKs

Answer (score 4):

Unless you set `innodb_file_per_table`, `ibdata1` holds all `InnoDB` tables plus undo.

This file never shrinks.

To shrink it, you should (at your own risk):

- Backup and drop **all** `InnoDB` tables in **all** databases
- Delete the file manually
- Reinitialize `InnoDB` storage (by restarting `mysqld`) and
- Restore the tables from backup.

If you set `innodb_file_per_table`, you'll still have to do this to reclaim the space, but in this case you'll be able to do this on per-table basis, without affecting the other tables.

Note that the undo is still held in `ibdata`, even with `innodb_file_per_table` set.

Answer (score 1):

[Adding, Removing, or Resizing InnoDB  Data and Log Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Run `optimize table your_db.your_table;` sql request 
or use [mysql workbench migration wizard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard.html) and it will create database copy with reduced size