# MySQL Inndob Delete/Purge rows from very large databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb, lamp

I am having some issues with deleting data from innodb tables, from what I am reading most people are saying the only way to free up space is to export the wanted data create a new tale and import it.. this seems a very rubbish way of doing it, especially on a data which is nearly 3tbs.

The issue I am having is deleting data older then 3 months to try and free up disk space, once the data is deleted the disk space does not seem to be freed up. Is there a way to purge or permanently delete rows/data to free up disk space?

Is there a more reliable way without dropping the database and restarting the service to free up disk space.

Please could some body advise me on the best approach to handling deletion of large database.

Much appreciate your time in advanced.

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL data file won't shrink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646373/mysql-data-file-wont-shrink)

Answer (score 5):

One relatively efficient approach is using [database partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html) and dropping old data by deleting partitions. It certainly requires more complicated maintenance, but it does work.

First, enable innodb_file_per_table so that each table (and partition) goes to its own file instead of a single huge ibdata file.

Then, create a partitioned table, having one partition per range of time (day, month, week, you pick it), which results in files of some sensible size for your data set.

```
create table foo(     
        tid INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        yearmonth INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        data varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (tid, yearmonth) 
) engine=InnoDB
PARTITION BY RANGE(yearmonth) (
        PARTITION p201304 VALUES LESS THAN (201304),
        PARTITION p201305 VALUES LESS THAN (201305),
        PARTITION p201306 VALUES LESS THAN (201306)
);
```

Looking in the database data directory you'll find a file for each partition. In this example, partition 'p201304' will contain all rows having yearmonth < 201304, 'p201305' will have rows for 2013-04, 'p201306' will contain all rows for 2013-05.

In practice I have actually used an integer column containing an UNIX timestamp as the partitioning key - that way it's easier to adjust the size of the partitions as time goes by. The partition edges do not need to match any calendar boundaries, they can happen every 100000 seconds or whatever results in a sensible amount of partitions (tens of partitions) while still having small enough files with your data.

Then, set up a maintenance process which creates new partitions for new data: `ALTER TABLE foo ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p201307 VALUES LESS THAN (201307))` and deletes old partitions: `ALTER TABLE foo DROP PARTITION p201304`. Deletion of a large partition is almost as fast as deleting the file, and it'll actually free up disk space. Also, it won't fragment the other partitions by leaving empty space scattered inside them.

If possible, make sure your frequent queries only access one or a few partitions by specifying the partition key (yearmonth in the example above), or a range of it, in the WHERE clause - that'll make them run much faster as the database won't need to look inside all the partitions to find your data.

Comment: I will have a play with your suggestion, Much appreciate your help.

Comment: How would this work if i wanted to delete from multiple tables at once using the id in table or I needed to use a join?

Comment: With a partitioned schema you'd do a "ALTER TABLE foo DROP PARTITION p201304" operation, which practically deletes a single partition file from disk, instantly purging a month of data (or whatever your partition time step happens to be). You can't do a JOIN. You can still delete smaller amounts of data with DELETE (with JOINs and all that), as before, but that won't give you the speed of a partition drop, and it won't reclaim disk space until the partition is dropped. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use the `file_per_table` option you will still have this issue. The only way to "fix" it is to rebuild individual tables:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE bloated_table
```

Note that this will lock the table during the rebuild operation, and you must have enough free space to accommodate the new table. On some systems this is impractical.

If you're frequently deleting data, you probably need to rotate the entire table periodically. Dropping a table under InnoDB with `file_per_table` will liberate the disk space almost immediately. If you have one table per month, you can simply drop tables representing data from three months ago.

Is it ugly to work with these? Yes. Is there an alternative? Not really. You can try going down the [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) rabbit hole, but that often ends up more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: What happens if the disk is pretty much full, will the optimize fail? I am guessing this would probably be an ok solution for regular maintenance. I think I may have missed the boat due to the db disk space being 100% (19gb free) I may have to do a painful move of the database to a larger disk drive and start a regular delete/optimize maintenance schedule. Does this sound like the best way to solve it? Thanks :)

Comment: OPTIMIZE TABLE will create a new copy of that table, and then delete the old one. If your table is large, and you don't have file_per_table set, that operation can make your ibdata file grow by the size of the new data set - and it won't shrink after that. Even with file_per_table, in a worst case setup of a single large table, a regular OPTIMIZE schedule may increase your disk space requirement since you need space for the table copy during OPTIMIZE. If you've got many large tables, it's less of a problem, but still, it'll lock your table for quite a while.

Comment: "Table per month" is an option that would work, but then you'll need additional special code in all of your INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE operations to pick the right tables. Using partitions moves that magic away to the partition creation/deletion maintenance code.

Comment: @oh7lzb It's all about picking your poison: Would you rather maintain a partition map in your database, or are you more comfortable working with application code that assigns the correct table name when doing operations? Both will work, but unless you're a veteran DBA, partitions can be trouble to manage.

Comment: I've been happy with partitions, since I haven't had to modify the SELECTs to do UNIONs over multiple tables using custom magic - thanks to partitions, the old queries in the applications work unmodified and a simple SELECT will look at one or more partitions as necessary. The maintenance code isn't too hard either, after all - just a single query to add a new partition every now and then, and another to drop an old one. It's a choice of least complexity, I've been happy with my choice so far.